# Windows VM becomes unresponsive and shows black screen after live migration on openstack

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rdp, openstack, live-migration

I have few Windows VM, running on KVM hypervisor in an openstack cloud, which becomes un responsive and shows black screen ( in Horizon dashboard console) and even RDP does not work. I have observed this issue post live migration for these VMs. I have to do a soft reboot to make it working.

Does anyone know what is causing this issue and how to fix it?